# accessing multiple Firebase db via one app

Tags: firebase, flutter

I"m trying to follow the instruction in the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects?fbclid=IwAR09ICDSr8WtJPNGHMAjDmjI5LaEVBavubm1bxghG_YYvp6SektuRQjUlxc) in order to use multiple projects application /accessing multiple database instances in my app because my application need to get data from a few FB instances (the user need to enter the FB details in run-time and not in advance via google-services.json

```
final FirebaseOptions SecondayDB_options = const FirebaseOptions( googleAppID: '1:7931046381656:android:2fb28f95a41bde78da062d', gcmSenderID: '7931046381656', apiKey: 'AIzaSyAvG7mVHoX0C_zim1D3UhUITF4ml7Be4fsI', );
```

and...

```
final FirebaseApp app = await FirebaseApp.configure( name: 'FB-1', options: SecondayDB_options, );
```

My question:
what is the next step?
how do I get the FirebaseAuth object-related?
How do I get the Firestore.instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have a `FirebaseApp` object, you can get a `FirebaseAuth` object for that with:

```
FirebaseAuth.fromApp(app)
```

And a `Firestore` object with:

```
Firestore(app)
```